# SQL Error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Tags: sql, oracle

I tried using the LISTAGG function before, but since there is a likelihood that the output would be pretty long, maybe even more than 4000 bytes.. I kept getting the error that the result of string concatenation is too long. I followed AskTom page that Tim references about the [implementation of a string aggregation function that returns a CLOB](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:2196162600402#29842804516386).

```
           CREATE TABLE FINAL_LOG AS
           SELECT SESSION_DT, C_IP, CS_USER_AGENT,
           concat_all_ot(WEB_LINK, ' ')
           WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY C_IP, CS_USER_AGENT) AS "WEBLINKS"
               FROM weblog_views
               GROUP BY C_IP, CS_USER_AGENT, SESSION_DT
               ORDER BY SESSION_DT
```

For this I get the following error,

SQL Error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong with this?

Comment: you don't need the `WITHIN GROUP` clause. it's ok only the function and its parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using a user-defined aggregate function, you probably need to omit the `WITHIN GROUP` clause.  It also doesn't make sense to specify an `ORDER BY` clause in a `CREATE TABLE` statement since the data in a heap-organized table is inherently unordered.  Also, if you are using the code in that link, the name of the aggregate function is `concat_all`.  `concat_all_ot` is the object type.  So you'd want something like

```
CREATE TABLE FINAL_LOG  AS   
  SELECT SESSION_DT, 
         C_IP, 
         CS_USER_AGENT,
         concat_all( concat_expr(WEB_LINK, ' ') ) AS "WEBLINKS"
    FROM weblog_views    
   GROUP BY C_IP, 
            CS_USER_AGENT, 
            SESSION_DT
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I get the error "not a GROUP BY expression".

Comment: @user1874311 - I edited my answer.  The name of the aggregate function on the link you provided is `concat_all` not `concat_all_ot`.

Comment: I did what you suggested, I get the following error,                SQL Error: ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CONCAT_ALL'

Comment: @user1874311 - Yup.  Missed a wrinkle.  Edited my answer.